# oracle.security.crypto.core.CipherException: Invalid padding string (or incorrect password)

Tags: java, oracle, ssl, jdbc, java-8

I am trying to access the db using SSL listener port using the code listed below.

```
import java.security.Security;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class SSLTester
{
public static void main(String[] args)
throws Exception
{
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
Security.insertProviderAt(new oracle.security.pki.OraclePKIProvider(), 3);
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = " +
"(ADDRESS_LIST = " +
"(ADDRESS = " +
"(PROTOCOL = TCPS)" +
"(HOST = <hostname>)" +
"(PORT = <port>)" +
")" +
") " +
"(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = <servicename>))" +
")";

java.util.Properties info = new java.util.Properties();
info.setProperty("oracle.net.authentication_services", "(TCPS)");
info.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "YOUR_WALLET_LOCATION/cwallet.sso");
info.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "SSO");
info.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "YOUR_WALLET_LOCATON/cwallet.sso");
info.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "SSO");

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, info);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select user from dual");

while (rset.next())
System.out.println(rset.getString(1));

rset.close();
stmt.close();
conn.close();
}
}
```

But I am seeing the error below. I tried updating the user id and passowrd using "setProperty" as well but still see the same error.

> java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could
>   not establish the connection  at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:673)    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:715)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:385)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:564)   at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)  at
>   TestOracleSSLConnection.main(TestOracleSSLConnection.java:22) Caused
>   by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not
>   establish the connection  at
>   oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:445)     at
>   oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:464)
>     at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:594)
>     at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:229)    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1360)     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:486)    ... 7
>   more Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unable to initialize ssl
>   context.  at
>   oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getSSLSocketFactory(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:325)
>     at oracle.net.nt.TcpsNTAdapter.connect(TcpsNTAdapter.java:115)  at
>   oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133)     at
>   oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:411)     ... 12 more
>   Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unable to initialize the trust
>   store.    at
>   oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getTrustManagerArray(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:413)
>     at
>   oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getSSLSocketFactory(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:309)
>     ... 15 more Caused by:
>   oracle.security.crypto.asn1.ASN1FormatException:
>   oracle.security.crypto.core.CipherException: Invalid padding string
>   (or incorrect password)   at
>   oracle.security.crypto.cert.PKCS12Safe.input(PKCS12Safe.java:226)     at
>   oracle.security.crypto.cert.PKCS12Safe.(PKCS12Safe.java:120)    at
>   oracle.security.crypto.cert.PKCS12.input(PKCS12.java:179)     at
>   oracle.security.crypto.cert.PKCS12.(PKCS12.java:119)    at
>   oracle.security.pki.OracleKeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(Unknown Source)  at
>   oracle.security.pki.OracleSSOKeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
>     at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)  at
>   oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getTrustManagerArray(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:404)
>     ... 16 more

Answer (score 0):

Can you check out the [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc%2C-tlsv12%2C-jks-or-oracle-wallets) for more details ? 
Oracle Wallets require oraclepki.jar, osdt_core.jar, and osdt_cert.jar.

Comment: Thanks , yes I’m using all the jars mentioned in my class path

Comment: Can you follow the blog and pass only the necessary connection properties ?

Comment: Thanks , this is now resolved. I was generating the certificate which seemed to be incorrect. It works after I started using the sso cert from the server.